# Python Problem: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'brett'

Tags: python, arduino, chess

I'm new to Python and i'm trying to programm a chessboard. I followed the steps by a Professor and now i want to implement the Possibility to get the Board(Where the pieces stand) from serial input (Arduino). Somehow im getting more and more Errors.

After i looked up for all, i cannot solve this one:

> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'brett'.

Here is my Code for the Board:

```py
import serial

class GameState:

    def __init__(self,brett):

        self.Board = [brett]
        self.moveFunctions = {"p": self.getPawnMoves, "R": self.getRookMoves, "N": self.getKnightMoves,
                              "B": self.getBishopMoves, "Q": self.getQueenMoves, "K": self.getKingMoves}
        self.white_to_move = True
        self.move_log = []
        self.white_king_location = (7, 4)
        self.black_king_location = (0, 4)
        self.checkmate = False
        self.stalemate = False
        self.in_check = False
        self.pins = []
        self.checks = []
        self.enpassant_possible = ()  # coordinates for the square where en-passant capture is possible
        self.enpassant_possible_log = [self.enpassant_possible]
        self.current_castling_rights = CastleRights(True, True, True, True)
        self.castle_rights_log = [CastleRights(self.current_castling_rights.wks, self.current_castling_rights.bks,
                                               self.current_castling_rights.wqs, self.current_castling_rights.bqs)]

    def brett(self):
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1)
            ser.flush()
            while True:
                if ser.in_waiting > 0:
                    brett = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
                    print(brett)
        else:
            brett = ['bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB', 'bN', 'bR'],['bp'] * 8,['--'] * 8, ['--'] * 8,['--'] * 8,['--'] * 8,['wp'] * 8,['wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB', 'wN', 'wR']
            print(brett)
```

and my main for the actualy Programm:

```py
def main():
    """
    The main driver for our code.
    This will handle user input and updating the graphics.
    """
    p.init()
    screen = p.display.set_mode((BOARD_WIDTH + MOVE_LOG_PANEL_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT))
    clock = p.time.Clock()
    screen.fill(p.Color("white"))
    game_state = ChessEngine.GameState()
    valid_moves = game_state.getValidMoves()
    move_made = False  # flag variable for when a move is made
    animate = False  # flag variable for when we should animate a move
    loadImages()  # do this only once before while loop

    running = True
    square_selected = ()  # no square is selected initially, this will keep track of the last click of the user (tuple(row,col))
    player_clicks = []  # this will keep track of player clicks (two tuples)
    game_over = False

    white_did_check = ""
    black_did_check = ""
    last_move_printed = False
    moves_list = []
    move_log_font = p.font.SysFont("Arial", 14, False, False)

    turn = 1

    player_one = True  # if a human is playing white, then this will be True, else False
    player_two = False  # if a hyman is playing white, then this will be True, else False
```

it tells me the Problem is in game_state = ChessEngine.GameState() but i dont know what to put there.
Thank you for your help

Comment: `ChessEngine.GameState(someBrett)` you set the init to receive a "brett" argument, so when calling it, pass one

Comment: What is the code in `def brett(self):` why is there a `if __name__ == '__main__':` ??

Comment: i dont get what `p` is in the code from `p.init()`. where is it created ?  can you please rephrase the question to just the erorr that you have so that others can replicate it and clearly send the problem that you are trying to resolve.

Comment: the def brett code is to receive the new board layout (8x8 array where the chess figures stand after a move). I dont know why it is in there, its just in the example Serial code i found and it worked like this,  so i am using it. 

and i cannot change ChessEngine.GameState(someBrett) because it will change every move. My aim is to get a new Brett every move a player makes and then i want the board to change

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, in `main()`, `game_state` is initialised without a `brett` argument:

```py
game_state = ChessEngine.GameState()
```

despite objects of your `ChessEngine.GameState` class requiring a `brett` argument for initialisation:

```py
class GameState:
    def __init__(self,brett):
        self.Board = [brett]
```

Hence, do something like this in `main()`:

```py
game_state = ChessEngine.GameState(value)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick help! Sadly i cant do game_state = ChessEngine.GameState(value), since i dont know the value yet. I will get a new Board for every move from the arduino

Comment: In this case, I would recommend following p3j4p5's suggestion and initialising GameState without the brett attribute and move brett outside of your __init__ method.

Answer (score 0):

In your `main()` function when you are initialising `GameState()` you need to pass in *something* that will be used as `brett` which in turn will be assigned to `self.Board` inside `GameState.__init__(self,brett)`.

In other words, in your `main()` function, the line:

```py
def main():
    ...
    game_state = ChessEngine.GameState()
    ...
```

needs to be replaced with:

```py
    ...
    game_state = ChessEngine.GameState(something_that_will_be_brett)
    ...
```

On the other hand, it looks like `GameState.Board` isn't used for anything, so maybe you could remove `Board` and change:

```py
class GameState:
    def __init__(self,brett):
        ...
```

to

```py
class GameState:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the Quick help! In my Programm when i write self.Board[....(8x8 array)...] everything works fine. Now i want to get this 8x8 array from the arduino and i called the incoming array brett. I now changed it like you said but it just doesnt want to work. Now its telling me:  ```` line 300, in checkForPinsAndChecks
    end_piece = self.board[end_row][end_col]
IndexError: list index out of range. 
even though the Information of brett is exact the same array that worked before. I really cant understand because for the computer the Information should be the same.

Comment: I would suggest to check the values of `end_row` and `end_col` (if you can), and make sure they are both smaller than 8 (i.e. 7 at max).